# Code behind WPF and F#

Tags: wpf, f#, c#-to-f#

Is it possible to make an application in F# that uses WPF with a classic code behind? I know it works perfect with MVVM and no code behind, but I need to implement an interface on a `UserControl`. Is that possible with F#?

To help a bit, here is the code I want to translate from C# to F#

```cs
public class Test : UserControl, IContent {

    public void InitializeComponents() {
        // Do the initialization magic
    }

    public Test() {
    }

    public void OnFragmentNavigation(FragmentNavigationEventArgs e) {
        this.DataContext = new { description = "Hallo Welt :)" };
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e){
    }

    public void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) {
    }
}
```

And this is the markup

```xml
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="Test">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"></TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Try this.. https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml

Comment: You don't "implement interfaces" in UserControls in WPF. Why would you do that?

Comment: @HighCore check here: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/wiki/Handle-navigation-events

Comment: @Knerd IMHO, an applications "navigation" features are a responsibility of the application itself, not the UI. in WPF, the ViewModels are the "application", not the Views, therefore that code doesn't belong in the UI, therefore you don't need any interfaces in the UI.

Comment: @HighCore, yes I do. The Framework handles the navigation events on the `UserControl`. I already opened an issue if it is possible to do it in the ViewModel ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, I just make it short, here is the code:

```
namespace Testns

open System.Windows.Controls
open FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core
open System

type TestUserControl() =
    inherit UserControl()

    interface IContent with
        member x.OnFragmentNavigation(e: Navigation.FragmentNavigationEventArgs): unit = 
            let vm = ViewModel("Hallo Welt :)")
            base.DataContext <- vm
            ()

        member x.OnNavigatedFrom(e: Navigation.NavigationEventArgs): unit = ()

        member x.OnNavigatedTo(e: Navigation.NavigationEventArgs): unit = ()

        member x.OnNavigatingFrom(e: Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs): unit = ()
```

And the markup

```
<local:TestUserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testns;assembly=App">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"></TextBlock>
</local:TestUserControl>
```

This is not the answer for the actual question, it just works for my use case. So feel free to answer it :)

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you mean by "classic code behind". As mentioned by Petr, F# does not have partial classes (and there is also no editor support), so you won't get the same experience (when you are accessing elements or adding events). But you can certainly build a WPF application that uses the same programming model.

One way to get something that is very close to standard code behind is to define a class, associated with each `xaml` file, that looks something like this:

```
type SomeComponent() =
  let uri = System.Uri("/AppName;component/SomeComponent.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
  let ctl = Application.LoadComponent(uri) :?> UserControl

  let (?) (this : Control) (prop : string) : 'T =
    this.FindName(prop) :?> 'T

  let okBtn : Button  = ctl?OkButton
  do okBtn.Click.Add(fun _ -> (* .. whatever *) )
```

This loads the XAML content and then uses the dynamic lookup operator to find all the UI elements (which you'd get for free in C#). A nicer F# solution is to use [FsXaml](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml), which has a XAML type provider (but sadly, not much documentation).

Comment: Check my edit, the code it self is great :) Might help with another problem I have ^^

Answer (score 1):

Probably no. As far as I know F# doesn't support partial classes.

But you can use F# XAML type provider as described here: http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/04/29/using-wpf-elements-from-f/